# Finding and averaging elements of multiple dataframes that are within 10% of each other

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, comparison

I have objects that store values are dataframes. I have been able to compare if values from two dataframes are within 10% of each other. However, I am having difficulty extending this to multiple dataframes. Moreover, I am wondering how I should apporach this problem if dataframes are not the same size?

```
def add_well_peak(self, *other):
       if len(self.Bell) == len(other.Bell): #if dataframes ARE the same size
           for k in range(len(self.Bell)):
               for j in range(len(other.Bell)):
                   if int(self.Size[k]) - int(self.Size[k])*(1/10) <= int(other.Size[j]) <= int(self.Size[k]) + int(self.Size[k])*(1/10):
#average all
```

For example, in the image below, there are objects that contain dataframes (i.e., self, other1, other2). The colors represent matches (i.e, values that are within 10% of each other). If a match exist, then average the values. If a match does not exist still include the unmatch number. I want to be able to generalize this for any number of objects greater or equal than 2 (other 1, other 2, other 3, other ....). Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if anything is unclear. This is my first time posting. Thanks again.

[matching data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U05fO.png)

Comment: First, how do you want to handle the case where one cell is within 10% of the other, but not the other way around (i.e. 1350 and 1500)? Second, the merging for different sizes could be done several ways: either stop at the shortest, or pad with default value, or average only the ones that you can, etc... This will depend on what you need it for, I suppose.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. On second thought, I think it would be best to see if the values are within 10% of the average of the numbers (i.e., average of 1350 and 1500 is 1425, which both are within 10% of). If that is not possible, it would be best to still average the values regardless if it fits one condition. For the second question, It would best to average only the ones you can.

Comment: Let's assume we have 4 datasets with first values 1500, 1350, 1200, 1080. What do you want as a result? 3 cells with 1500, 1282.5 and 1080?

Comment: Yes, I would like that to be the output.

Comment: And in the case 1500, 1000, 1500? Do you want to group the identical cells together? Additionally, your image isn't corresponding to what you've described to me anymore, I think.

Comment: Your right. I think it is a bit different from the image. This approach would be better: 
 Case 1 (1500, 1350, 1200, 1080): output should be 1425 and 1140. So, I would recommend averaging 1500 & 1350 together and the 1200 & 1080 together.                         Case 2 (1500, 1000, 1500): output should be 1500 and 1000 (group identical cells together). Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it. Sorry if I am not explaining things clearly enough.

Comment: The case 1 raises questions still. 1350 is within 10% of 1500, but the opposite is not true. Additionally, what do you want as a result in the following case (1000, 1100, 1210, 1331)?

Comment: Is there something in particular you are trying to do? Or is it a personal project/problem? If it is motivated by wanting to do something in particular, could you share it? It might help in understanding what it is you want and especially what it is you need.

Comment: Yes, it's a personal project! I am trying to see whether there are peaks (i.e., sizes) that are present in different bells. For instance, is there a 1500 peak/size (or similar) in different bells? The data itself has many repeats but these repeats have deviations (e.g., 1500 vs 1487 or 5144 vs. 5286). If the peaks deviate by some amount (10%), then still consider them close matches or similar peaks. Thankfully, most of the data has identical peaks (e.g., 5144 both in df1 & df2) but there are still some deviations.

Comment: Case 1, would most likely not happen with my dataset since there are very small deviations between numbers. For simplicity, I think it would be best to not average matches that are not within 10% in both directions (i.e., ignore the set 1500,1350,1200,1080 or 1000,1100,1210,1331).

Comment: The output should be a dataset that identifies identical/similar peaks from different dataframes, and the output should identify peaks that are not present in the other dataframes by listing them. In the image, 78486, 45968 and 100,000 have no similar matches so still list them in the output but dont average them with any other values.

Comment: While I try doing this, may I suggest you look into Dynamic Time Warping? It seems to strongly resemble what you are trying to do. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)

Comment: Also what is the point in having this output dataset, when you won't be able to know if a value corresponds to the next value or another value from the same cell that isn't in the 10%? Wouldn't it be better to have a list of lists (as many lists as there are cells) with first the average 10%-value and then the outliers?

Comment: I never thought about that approach. Now that I think about it would be best to have a dataframe with the average 10%-value and then another dataframe with the outliers. I would prefer dataframes over list since all the data provided is given in an excel file. The hardest part for me is thinking about how you would find matches that are within 10% in both directions (for more than two dataframes),  and how to deal with outliers that are not in 10% with any of the values in separate dataframes. Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: To make it easier (possible?) you'd have to settle on grouping the cells of same indices together only (meaning you can't "miss" a color and regroup later as you've done in your df3 in your image). If you'd like this to be possible, again look into the DTW approach, it is made for this.

Comment: How would DTW work for more than two dataframes? I'm currently looking into python documentation on it.

Comment: Haven't thought about more than two dfs, you're right. If the lengths differ, how are you supposed to know whether the value of a cell is an outlier or a value for the "next round"? Is there a threshold that could be admissible?

Comment: Thats the tricky part. I have not been able to think of a solution, but one idea I had was merging the separate dataframes together into a 'full dataframe' and then finding matches within that 'full dataframe'. The values that do not match would not be altered. Only problem with this approach is how do you label the 'Bell' name (A1 vs A1 A2 A3) to consider matches and non-matches?

Comment: There is no given threshold. However, the maximum size is always 100,000 and the minimum size is always 1. There could be any number of peaks in between those ranges.

Comment: That I understood, my point is: in the case (1500, 1700, 8000) how are we supposed to know that 8000 isn't just a big outlier, but must not be considered for this cell. Is there a threshold (like 150% of the avg of the rest)?

Comment: There is no threshold given but I think using the IQR could be able to tell whether an outlier exist (e.g., Q1 – 1.5 IQR or above Q3 + 1.5 IQR are outliers) for any number of datapoints, so 150% of the average should be a good enough estimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Results:

Using my solution on the dataframes of your image, I get the following:
Threshold outlier = 0.2:

```py
               0
0       1.000000
1    1493.500000
2    5191.333333
3   35785.333333
4   43586.500000
5   78486.000000
6  100000.000000
```

Threshold outlier = 0.5:

```py
              0              1
0      1.000000            NaN
1   1493.500000            NaN
2   5191.333333            NaN
3  43586.500000   35785.333333
4  78486.000000  100000.000000
```

### Explanations:

The lines are averaged peaks, the columns representing the different values obtained for these peaks. I assumed the average emanating from the biggest number of elements was the legitimate one, and the rest within the `THRESHOLD_OUTLIER` were the outliers (should be sorted, the more probable you are as a legitimate peak, the more you are on the left (the 0th column is the most probable)). For instance, on line 3 of the 0.5 outlier threshold results, `43586.500000` is an average coming from 3 dataframes, while `35785.333333` comes from only 2, thus the most probable is the first one.

### Issues:

The solution is quite complicated. I assume a big part of it could be removed, but I can't see how for the moment, and as it works, I'll certainly leave the optimization to you.
Still, I tried commenting my best, and if you have any question, do not hesitate!

### Files:

CombinationLib.py

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Dict, List
from Errors import *

class Combination():
    """
        Support class, to make things easier.  
        
        Contains a string `self.combination` which is a binary number stored as a string.
        This allows to test every combination of value (i.e. "101" on the list `[1, 2, 3]`
        would signify grouping `1` and `3` together).

        There are some methods:
        - `__add__` overrides the `+` operator
        - `compute_degree` gives how many `1`s are in the combination
        - `overlaps` allows to verify if combination overlaps (use the same value twice) 
        (i.e. `100` and `011` don't overlap, while `101` and `001` do)
    """
    def __init__(self, combination:str) -> Combination:
        self.combination:str = combination
        self.degree:int = self.compute_degree()
    def __add__(self, other: Combination) -> Combination:
        if self.combination == None:
            return other.copy()
        if other.combination == None:
            return self.copy()
        if self.overlaps(other):
            raise CombinationsOverlapError()
        result = ""
        for c1, c2 in zip(self.combination, other.combination):
            result += "1" if (c1 == "1" or c2 == "1") else "0"
        return Combination(result)
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.combination
    def compute_degree(self) -> int:
        if self.combination == None:
            return 0
        degree = 0
        for bit in self.combination:
            if bit == "1":
                degree += 1
        return degree
    def copy(self) -> Combination:
        return Combination(self.combination)
    def overlaps(self, other:Combination) -> bool:
        for c1, c2 in zip(self.combination, other.combination):
            if c1 == "1" and c1 == c2:
                return True
        return False

class CombinationNode():
    """
        The main class.

        The main idea was to build a tree of possible "combinations of combinations":

        100-011 => 111

        |---010-001 => 111

        |---001-010 => 111

        At each node, the combination applied to the current list of values was to be acceptable
        (all within THREASHOLD_AVERAGING).

        Also, the shorter a path, the better the solution as it means it found a way to average
        a lot of the values, with the minimum amount of outliers possible, maybe by grouping
        the outliers together in a way that makes sense, ...

        - `populate` fills the tree automatically, with every solution possible
        - `path` is used mainly on leaves, to obtain the path taken to arrive there.
    """
    def __init__(self, combination:Combination) -> CombinationNode:
        self.combination:Combination = combination
        self.children:List[CombinationNode] = []
        self.parent:CombinationNode = None
        self.total_combination:Combination = combination
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        list_paths = self.recur_paths()
        list_paths = [",".join([combi.combination.combination for combi in path]) for path in list_paths]
        return "\n".join(list_paths)
    def add_child(self, child:CombinationNode) -> None:
        if child.combination.degree > self.combination.degree and not self.total_combination.overlaps(child.combination):
            raise ChildDegreeExceedParentDegreeError(f"{child.combination} > {self.combination}")
        self.children.append(child)
        child.parent = self
        child.total_combination += self.total_combination
    def path(self) -> List[CombinationNode]:
        path = []
        current = self
        while current.parent != None:
            path.append(current)
            current = current.parent
        path.append(current)
        return path[::-1]
    def populate(self, combination_dict:Dict[int, List[Combination]]) -> None:
        missing_degrees = len(self.combination.combination)-self.total_combination.degree
        if missing_degrees == 0:
            return
        for i in range(min(self.combination.degree, missing_degrees), 0, -1):
            for combination in combination_dict[i]:
                if not self.total_combination.overlaps(combination):
                    self.add_child(CombinationNode(combination))
        for child in self.children:
            child.populate(combination_dict)
    def recur_paths(self) -> List[List[CombinationNode]]:
        if len(self.children) == 0:
            return [self.path()]
        paths = []
        for child in self.children:
            for path in child.recur_paths():
                paths.append(path)
        return paths
```

Errors.py

```py
class ChildDegreeExceedParentDegreeError(Exception):
    pass
class CombinationsOverlapError(Exception):
    pass
class ToImplementError(Exception):
    pass
class UncompletePathError(Exception):
    pass
```

main.py

```py
from typing import Dict, List, Set, Tuple, Union
import pandas as pd
from CombinationLib import *

best_depth:int = -1
best_path:List[CombinationNode] = []

THRESHOLD_OUTLIER = 0.2
THRESHOLD_AVERAGING = 0.1

def verif_averaging_pct(combination:Combination, values:List[float]) -> bool:
    """
        For a given combination of values, we must have all the values within 
        THRESHOLD_AVERAGING of the average of the combination
    """
    avg = 0
    for c,v in zip(combination.combination, values):
        if c == "1":
            avg += v
    avg /= combination.degree
    for c,v in zip(combination.combination, values):
        if c == "1"and (v > avg*(1+THRESHOLD_AVERAGING) or v < avg*(1-THRESHOLD_AVERAGING)):
            return False
    return True
def recursive_check(node:CombinationNode, depth:int, values:List[Union[float, int]]) -> None:
    """
        Here is where we preferencially ask for a small number of bigger groups
    """
    global best_depth
    global best_path
    # If there are more groups than the current best way to do, stop
    if best_depth != -1 and depth > best_depth:
        return
    # If all the values of the combination are not within THRESHOLD_AVERAGING, stop
    if not verif_averaging_pct(node.combination, values):
        return
    # If we finished the list of combinations, and this way is the best, keep it, stop
    if len(node.children) == 0:
        if best_depth == -1 or depth < best_depth:
            best_depth = depth
            best_path = node.path()
        return
    # If we are still not finished (not every value has been used), continue
    for cnode in node.children:
        recursive_check(cnode, depth+1, values)
def groups_from_list(values:List[Union[float, int]]) -> List[List[Union[float, int]]]:
    """
        From a list of values, get the smallest list of groups of elements 
        within THRESHOLD_AVERAGING of each other.
        It implies that we will try and recursively find the biggest group possible
        within the unsused values (i.e. groups with combinations of size [3, 1] are prefered 
        over [2, 2])
    """
    global best_depth
    global best_path

    groups:List[List[float]] = []
    
    # Generate all the combinations (I used binary for this)
    combination_dict:Dict[int, List[Combination]] = {}
    for i in range(1, 2**len(values)):
        combination = format(i, f"0{len(values)}b") # Here is the binary conversion
        counter = 0
        for c in combination:
            if c == "1":
                counter += 1
        if counter not in combination_dict:
            combination_dict[counter] = []
        combination_dict[counter].append(Combination(combination))

    # Generate of the combinations of combinations that use all values (without using one twice)
    combination_trees:List[List[CombinationNode]] = []
    for key in combination_dict:
        for combination in combination_dict[key]:
            cn = CombinationNode(combination)
            cn.populate(combination_dict)
            combination_trees.append(cn)

    best_depth = -1
    best_path = None

    for root in combination_trees:
        recursive_check(root, 0, values)

    # print(",".join([combination.combination.combination for combination in best_path]))

    for combination in best_path:
        temp = []
        for c,v in zip(combination.combination.combination, values):
            if c == "1":
                temp.append(v)
        groups.append(temp)

    return groups


def averages_from_groups(gs:List[List[Union[float, int]]]) -> List[float]:
    """Computing the averages of each group"""
    avgs:List[float] = []
    for group in gs:
        avg = 0
        for elt in group:
            avg += elt
        avg /= len(group)
        avgs.append(avg)
    return avgs
def end_check(ds:List[pd.DataFrame], ids:List[int]) -> bool:
    """Check if we finished consuming all the dataframes"""
    for d,i in zip(ds, ids):
        if i < len(d[0]):
            return False
    return True
def search(group:List[Union[float, int]], values_list:List[Union[float, int]]) -> List[int]:
    """Obtain all the indices corresponding to a set of values"""
    # We will get all the indices in values_list of the values in group
    # If a value is present in group, all the occurences of this value will be too, 
    # so we can use a set and search every occurence for each value.
    indices:List[int] = []
    group_set = set(group)
    for value in group_set:
        for i,v in enumerate(values_list):
            if value == v:
                indices.append(i)
    return indices
def threshold_grouper(total_list:List[Union[float, int]]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Building a 2D pd.DataFrame with the averages (x) and the outliers (y)"""
    result_list:List[List[Union[float, int]]] = [[total_list[0]]]

    result_index = 0
    total_index = 1
    while total_index < len(total_list):
        # Only checking if the bigger one is within THRESHOLD_OUTLIER of the little one.
        # If it is the case, the opposite is true too.
        # If yes, it is an outlier
        if result_list[result_index][0]*(1+THRESHOLD_OUTLIER) >= total_list[total_index]:
            result_list[result_index].append(total_list[total_index])
        # Else it is a new peak
        else:
            result_list.append([total_list[total_index]])
            result_index += 1
        total_index += 1

    result:pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
    return result
def dataframes_merger(dataframes:List[pd.DataFrame]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Merging the dataframes, with THRESHOLDS"""
    # Store the averages for the within 10% cells, in ascending order
    result = []

    # Keep tabs on where we are regarding each dataframe (needed for when we skip cells)
    curr_indices:List[int] = [0 for _ in range(len(dataframes))]
    # Repeat until all the cells in every dataframe has been seen once 
    while not end_check(dataframes, curr_indices):
        # Get the values of the current indices in the dataframes
        curr_values = [dataframe[0][i] for dataframe,i in zip(dataframes, curr_indices)]
        # Get the largest 10% groups from the current list of values
        groups = groups_from_list(curr_values)
        # Compute the average of these groups
        avgs = averages_from_groups(groups)
        # Obtain the minimum average...
        avg_min = min(avgs)
        # ... and its index
        avg_min_index = avgs.index(avg_min)
        # Then get the group corresponding to the minimum average
        avg_min_group = groups[avg_min_index]
        # Get the indices of the values included in this group
        indices_to_increment = search(avg_min_group, curr_values)
        # Add the average to the result merged list
        result.append(avg_min)
        # For every element in the average we added, increment the corresponding index
        for index in indices_to_increment:
            curr_indices[index] += 1
    
    # Re-assemble the dataframe, taking the threshold% around average into account
    result = threshold_grouper(result)
    print(result)

df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 1487, 5144, 35293, 78486, 100000])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([1, 1500, 5144, 36278, 45968, 100000])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([1, 5286, 35785, 41205, 100000])
dataframes_merger([df3, df2, df1])
```

Comment: If everything works as you wanted, could you mark the answer as a solution?